# How to add properties for all the keys and values in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

I have a Javascript Object :

```
{
    "Central":73322346.47533998,
    "East":87801368.39711998,
    "North":76468694.37534,
    "South":142687496.66816995,
    "West":76815749.40554999
}
```

I want to map this object into an array that look like this

```
[
    {"name" :"Central ,"size" : 73322346.47533998},
    {"name" : "East", "size" : 87801368.39711998},
    {"name": "North","size":76468694.37534},
    {"name": "South","size" :142687496.66816995},
    {"name":"West","size":76815749.40554999}
]
```

How do I go about?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Also note that duplicate key names will overwrite previous values assigned to those keys. Your desired output is invalid.

Comment: What is the purpose of array in this case?

Comment: Your output array of object has duplicate key name as `name` and `size` which is invalid

Comment: @CertainPerformance Edited the question to add the curly braces to separate the objects.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal edited the question

Comment: @MohammadUsman pls see updated question

Comment: @SyedAriff added answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this:

```
obj = {"Central":73322346.47533998,"East":87801368.39711998,"North":76468694.37534,"South":142687496.66816995,"West":76815749.40554999}
out = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(d){ out.push({name: d, size: obj[d]});})
//out will contain your formatted data
```

[image]

Comment: You can add a snippet in order to show your stuffs in action, screenshot doesn't help that much to have compare to some live code in action.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee sure I'll do that next time :)

Answer (score 2):

In ES2017 you can do:

`Object.entries(obj).map(([name, size])=> ({name, size}))`

```js
var obj = {
    "Central":73322346.47533998,
    "East":87801368.39711998,
    "North":76468694.37534,
    "South":142687496.66816995,
    "West":76815749.40554999
}

var res = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, size])=> ({name, size}));

console.log(res);
```

In ES2011 (5.1), ES2015 (6),.... and onward you can do:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
    return {name: k, size: obj[k]}
})
```

```js
var obj = {
    "Central":73322346.47533998,
    "East":87801368.39711998,
    "North":76468694.37534,
    "South":142687496.66816995,
    "West":76815749.40554999
}

var res = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
    return {name: k, size: obj[k]}
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `key`s of the object to get the array of objects as expected:

```js
var data = {"Central":73322346.47533998,"East":87801368.39711998,"North":76468694.37534,"South":142687496.66816995,"West":76815749.40554999};
var res = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=>{
  res.push({
    name: key,
    size: data[key]
  });
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to interate over the keys of the input object using a [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
const input = {
    "Central": 73322346.47533998,
    "East": 87801368.39711998,
    "North": 76468694.37534,
    "South": 142687496.66816995,
    "West": 76815749.40554999
};

let output = [];
for (const key in input)
{
    output.push({ "name": key, "size": input[key] });
}

console.log(output);
```

This is probably the fastest way to achieve the desired output.